# Is it possible to build an interface with R studio supported by AWS to visual studio 2015

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, visual-studio-2015, aws-sdk, rstudio-server

I am using R studio appliance supported by AWS for a prediction model.

I would like to develop a dashboard in visual studio 2015.

Could any one suggest me how i could do it ?

Comment: I assume, dashboard will be looking at some data? Wehre do you store this data?

Comment: I have my data stored in s3 bucket

Comment: @VictorS I am reading my data from S3, doing my predictions and writing my preiction results back to S3.